# compiling opencv code with openNI NITE Kinect on mac 64bit

Tags: opencv, makefile, kinect, openni

I've been trying to compile my code with opencv and openNI NITE. Finally got rid of all errors, now it runs without errors and I get my main.o but I'm not getting an executable file. below are the contents of my makefile

---

OSTYPE := $(shell uname -s)

SRC_FILES = \
    ../RGB_display/main.cpp

INC_DIRS += ../RBG_display  -I/opt/local/include/opencv

EXE_NAME = RGB_display

DEFINES = USE_GLUT

DEBUG_LEVEL     = -m64 -g3 -O0 
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -O3 -I/opt/local/include/opencv -L/opt/local/lib/
LIBS = -lhighgui -lcvaux -lcv -lml -lcxcore -lopencv_imgproc

LDFLAGS = `pkg-config --libs opencv`

ifeq ("$(OSTYPE)","Darwin")
        LDFLAGS += -framework OpenGL -framework GLUT
else
        USED_LIBS += glut
endif

$(EXE_NAME): main.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(EXE_NAME) $(LDFLAGS)

main.o: main.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c main.cpp $(LDFLAGS)

include ../NiteSampleMakefile

---

Does anybody know what's possibly wrong with this? Thanks! I'm using opencv with macports.